# Vaadin custom client side widget cannot compile 'No plugin found for prefix 'vaadin''

Tags: maven, widget, vaadin

I trying to create a custom client side widget with eclipse IDE. when i click compile widgetset option from the toolbar it stops with following error. This topic is a duplicate, but no suitable answer.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Downloading: 
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-
metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloading: 
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloaded: 
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-
metadata.xml (13 KB at 6.2 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloaded: 
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml 
(20 KB at 8.4 KB/sec)
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
---
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
---
[INFO] Total time: 5.004 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-07-04T15:48:53+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/143M
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
---
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'vaadin' in the current project and in 
the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available 
from the repositories [local (C:\Users\xxxx\.m2\repository), central 
(https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e 
switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please 
read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1]
```

My Pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>logicalintelligence.widget.navigationdrawer</groupId>
    <artifactId>navigationdrawer</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Navigationdrawer Add-on</name>

    <prerequisites>
        <maven>3</maven>
    </prerequisites>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <vaadin.version>7.7.10</vaadin.version>
        <vaadin.plugin.version>7.7.10</vaadin.plugin.version>

        <!-- ZIP Manifest fields -->
        <Implementation-Version>${project.version}</Implementation-Version>
        <!-- Must not change this because of the Directory -->
        <Implementation-Title>${project.name}</Implementation-Title>
        <Implementation-Vendor>${project.organization.name}</Implementation-Vendor>
        <Vaadin-License-Title>Apache License 2.0</Vaadin-License-Title>
        <Vaadin-Addon>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar</Vaadin-Addon>
    </properties>


    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>Apache 2</name>
            <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
            <distribution>repo</distribution>
        </license>
    </licenses>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>vaadin-addons</id>
            <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-server</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-client</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- This can be replaced with TestNG or some other test framework supported by the surefire plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <index>true</index>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <!-- Package format version - do not change -->
                            <Vaadin-Package-Version>1</Vaadin-Package-Version>
                            <Vaadin-License-Title>${Vaadin-License-Title}</Vaadin-License-Title>
                            <Vaadin-Widgetsets>logicalintelligence.widget.navigationdrawer.navigationdrawer.WidgetSet</Vaadin-Widgetsets>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-javadoc</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Testing -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <!-- This is needed for the sources required by the client-side compiler to be
            included in the produced JARs -->
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>rebel.xml</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>

    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- Vaadin pre-release repositories -->
            <id>vaadin-prerelease</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>

            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
                    <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases</url>
                </repository>
                <repository>
                    <id>vaadin-snapshots</id>
                    <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots/</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
                    <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases</url>
                </pluginRepository>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>vaadin-snapshots</id>
                    <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots/</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

Comment: After a quick look at your pom, it look like it's missing a [vaadin-maven-plugin configuration](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/clientside/clientside-compiling.html#clientside.compiling.maven). I'm not using Eclipse and from the docs it's not really clear if the eclipse plugin uses maven, but from your execution logs it would seem that way.

Answer (score 3):

Yes [Morfic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/474287/morfic) is right, I solved the problem by adding followings to the pom.xml

```
     <plugin>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>update-theme</goal>
                        <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <!-- Comment out compile-theme goal to use on-the-fly theme compilation -->
                        <goal>compile-theme</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```